# PHP translating via csv file

Tags: php, csv, translation

I have written a small PHP function to read a CSV file as source of Language(s).

```
class getLang {
   var $lang;
   function __construct() {
        $theBigArray = file('/inc/lang.csv');
        foreach ($theBigArray as $key => $value) {
           $line = explode(',', $value);
           $this->lang[trim($line[0])] = trim($line[1]);
        } 
   }    
}
```

Imagine the CSV file has a content like this :

```
Hello , Hallo
goodbye , Vaarwel
pizza , pizza
food , voedsel
morning , ochtend-
thanks, dank je
morning , Goedemorgen
nice , Leuk je te zien
day , goedendag
...
last_word , laatste woord
```

It's working well, for what I need, but I'm looking for a **better idea** to read CSV file and return a simple array or an object.

Note : Regarding, such CSV file will be filled out by a person(s) who don't know the programming and mostly, they use MS Excel to fill/make the CSV file, But we not talking about Regular expression in this post.

Best regard

Comment: See [fgetcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Comment: You can swap your explode line to `$line = str_getcsv($value);` to bypass potential enclosure/escape issues.